# How to avoid interpreting special symbols in command line arguments

Tags: linux

It is possible to avoid interpreting special "Unix/Linux reserved" symbols in the terminal?
For example, say that I have the following small C code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc >= 1) {
    printf("Argument: %s\n", argv[1]);
  }
}
```

Now, If I pass as argument the following line

```
  ./my_program 100$$
```

The result that will get printed is "**10028592**", even if I try with double quotes, e.g "100$$".
The same applies to other special symbols, e.g "&", "!!", "(" ..

Is there any way to pass those symbols as arguments?

Comment: Yes, use single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to indicate which shell you are using, as different shells might have different quoting rules.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, it looks like you are using the Bash shell, or a shell similar for it.

Quoting the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html), particularly [its chapter on quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html#Quoting):

> #### 3.1.2.2 Single Quotes
>
> Enclosing characters in **single quotes** (‘'’) **preserves the literal
> value of each character within the quotes**. A single quote may not
> occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> #### 3.1.2.3 Double Quotes
>
> Enclosing characters in **double quotes** (‘"’) preserves the literal
> value of all characters within the quotes, **with the exception of**
> ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’. [...]